# Combine Vue.js and Node Express projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

So my situation is: I have two projects in Visual Studio. One is the Node express API and the second is Vue SPA. My question is: how to run it at one time so I can test the interaction between API and client. I try to run a two projects separately and in a one solution but always one of it always doesn't start, even if they are running on different ports (for example 1337, 1991 maybe error is there). And CDN version not for me too.

Comment: Please provide the errors that you receive when they're running on different ports.

Comment: I have no actual errors in Node cmd, it just write "Debugger attached" twice if Express was started first and default Vue text else. But Firefox open only one page at one time (Home.vue or Index.pug) and write "Firefox cannot establish a connection to localhost" while I try to get other page (same with requests).

Comment: In all honesty, using VS for Vue/Node is an insane amount of overhead for such a light project. I highly recommend switching to VS Code for the terminal where you can run whatever scripts separately concurrently.